# Ruby: File.read Error encoding:"UTF-8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, encoding

I wrote a program to convert a xml file.
I started it with the following command

```
ruby Skribt.rb example
```

Here is a part of the code:

```
sessionid = ARGV[0].dup
inputfile = "upload/" + sessionid + "_source.xml" # Hochgeladene XML Datei
outputfile = "output/" + sessionid + ".xml"
stringKomplett = File.read(inputfile,encoding: "UTF-8").gsub(/<group.*?type=\"public\".*?\/>/, "")
```

I get the following error and do not know how to solve this.

```
Skript.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
... File.read(inputfile,encoding: "UTF-8").gsub(/<group.*?type=...
                              ^
Skript.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
...d(inputfile,encoding: "UTF-8").gsub(/<group.*?type=\"public\...
                          ^
```

I hope you can help me with this problem.
Thank you in advance for you help.

Greetings

Comment: what ruby version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using older Ruby version. Try this instead:

```
File.read(inputfile, :encoding => "UTF-8").gsub(/<group.*?type=\"public\".*?\/>/, "")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a bit strange, that apt-get says, that I have the newest version of ruby and at the same time ruby -v says I have 1.87. But now it does its task, so everything ok :)

Comment: @Firevulture thats great. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem :)